# Validate http request input for additionalProperties

Tags: json, go

I am trying to validate a http POST request and want to reject the request if it has any additional properties.

The struct I am expecting:

```
type RestPermissionDataV2 struct {
    // required:true
    Method string `json:"method" validate:"required"`
    // required:true
    Path string `json:"path" validate:"required"`
}

var permData RestPermissionDataV2

dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
if err := dec.Decode(&permData); err != nil {
    // return error
}
```

Now, even if I pass `{ "method": "POST", "path": "/api/path", "a": "B"}` , the validator validates the request. Is there anyway to invalidate it if the json object has extra parameters like **"a"** in this case?

Comment: I don't think the struct validator has such an option. But you can use the default JSON package `DisallowUnknownFields` - https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields

Comment: use "gopkg.in/validator.v2" and then use something like this `if err := validator.Validate(&permData); err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 }`

Comment: In the `"encoding/json"` package there is `Unmarshal` method that returns an error if additional fields are there

Answer (score 0):

In the `"encoding/json"` package there is `Unmarshal` method that returns error if additional properties are there.

Example

```golang
// considering your data as follows
jsonData := `{"method": "POST", "path": "/api/path", "a": "B"}`

type RestPermissionDataV2 struct {
    Method string `json:"method" validate:"required"`
    Path string `json:"path" validate:"required"`
}

var permData RestPermissionDataV2

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &permData)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Invalid JSON:", err)
    return
}
```

So this will produce a error like this `Invalid JSON: json: unknown field "a"`

Comment: It wouldn't work. JSON Unmarshall doesn't care for extra field. https://go.dev/play/p/PRQ-DGRBi8X